# How is a const char* not a just a character?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I'm really confused about this because personally, I come from a java background, and recently began c++. So, I learnt all the basic stuff, like, printing stuff out to the screen and whatnot, and now, I learnt POINTERS. So, the person on youtube ([The Cherno's C++ Pointer tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTxHyVn0ODg&index=16&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb) This was not the video where he declared the const char*, just the pointer tutorial that I followed.) I've been following was using this following statement to declare what I know as a 'string'.

```
const char* str = "random text here";
```

But, how is a char* converted into a string, and its even using the double quotation marks like a string! Also, what does a constant have to do with any of this? If I remove the `const` from my code it gives me an error. But, I understand what a pointer is. It is a variable that holds the memory address of another variable, so if one was to access that variable directly, they would just have to do `*ptrVarName` and dereferenced it. But how can a string `"like this one"` be a memory address?
Wouldn't I have to do something like this?

```
char[] str = "string here";
```

and THEN do:

```
char* stringPointer = *str;
```

(WARNING: untested code!)

Thanks in advance.
(oh and sorry if this is a really NOOBY question or the question is poorly constructed, I've just started out with c++ and stackoverflow)

**EDIT**: Ok, so I understand what the `char* str` means. It means that when you reference `*str`, it means that you're accessing the first character in memory. Ok, I get it now. But, what does **const** mean?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  You get a much more complete education from one of those then random online tutorials.

Comment: If you are using C++, why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: Indeed, from `T*`, we cannot know if there is one or several objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const char* str = "random text here";
> ```

On the right hand side, the `"random text here"` defines a string literal which actually is an array of type `const char[17]` (including the null terminator character). When you assign that array to `const char* str` it [*decays*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a pointer that points to the first character. You cannot modify the string literal through the pointer because string literals are stored in read-only memory, so the following would be illegal: `str[0] = 'x';`

> ```
> char[] str = "string here";
> ```

This one is different. It defines the `char` array `str` which has the same size as the string literal on the right hand side (`const char[12]`). The string literal will be copied into the array `str`, so you will be able to modify `str`. In this case, it would be legal to write `str[0] = 'x';`.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare const char* sth ="mystring" 
It will place mystring inthe memory and sth pointing to that its work like array but with direct access to memory

Comment: but you still havent answered my sub-question "what does the const mean?"

Comment: As petar velv said no difference net them

Comment: But, Amir (heh you have the same pronounced name as me), when i use char* str = "some text"; c++ gives an error

Comment: @AmeerAli `const` is short for "constant."  It means, a value that may not be modified.  `const MyType foo = ...;` declares a that `foo` holds a value of type `MyType` that may not be modified.  `const MyType* bar;` declares that `bar` holds a pointer to a value of type `MyType` that may not be modified.  Note that in the second case, the pointer `bar` _may_ be modified.  The thing that can't be modified is whatever `bar` points to.

Comment: Because "mystring" is const and it cant be put it to non const

Answer (score 0):

These are plain C-strings. A C string is always null terminated. In other words- it has `'\0'` at the end. So you need only the place in memory where the string starts and you can find when it ends.

For pointer arithmetic these [] brackets are only syntax sugar. `str[]` is the same as `*str` and `str[1]` is the same as `*(str+1)` only incrementing the pointer by one `char` (8 bits) and getting the address of the second element.

Comment: Ameer - you really need to just get a good book and read about pointers and pointer arithmetic. `(*str)+1` means "dereference the pointer `str` and add one to the result. `*(str+1)` means "add `1*sizeof(str)` to the pointer `str` and *then* dereference"

Comment: yes, i understand. I realized when I tried something in my text editor, then I understood. And anyway, I'm broke and don't have any money to buy a book ;(

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't really have strings. A string is an array of characters, terminated by a nul (0). Now arrays and pointers in C are closely linked, and a char * or const char * usually points to a string, but only in the same way as other pointers usually point to arrays. An individual char * might only point to a single character, you have to know from context, just as an int * might point to one integer or an array of integers.

Because strings are handy, there's a special syntactical rule for strings literal. A string literal in quotes becomes a const char * (in fact its type is char * for backwards compatibility). So in this sense, C has strings. But all that is happening is that the string is being laid out in the data section of the program, then its address taken.